# How to remove all top level domain names using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have list of domain names such as:

```
i.gr-assets.com
instacam.com
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.com
```

I want to remove the top level domain names. My output should look like in the below format:

```
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
```

Please note that I need to remove multiple top level domains and not just `.com` as my small example shows so I'm looking for a way to replace all that I specify I need to have removed and not just one.

How can I do this using Notepad++?

Comment: Using the Ctrl+H option go to the Replace tab and then put `.com` in the "Find What" field and have `<nothing leave it blank>` in the "Replace With" field and set the Wrap Around check, the Regular Expression checked (normal mode would work too) and select "Replace All". See if that does it by testing. Here's an image of the options: https://i.imgur.com/RheE0jf.png

Comment: It's also worth noting that any replacements you do can be done successively while recording a macro for future re-use.

Comment: not only for .com. Like this, I have so many top level domain names.  In a text file, in each domain name, i want to remove the top level domain name.  But here some domain names has more than one full stop

Comment: @vinayakumarR See the **Multiple String Replacement** section I added to my answer since you clarified what you needed was to remove more than just one top level domain and you only provided a small simple example in your question. Let me know how that goes when you get to it.

Comment: You should update your sample list with different extensions and edge cases. Why would you want to do it with Notepad++ specifically?

Comment: If you mean to remove domains extensions that have more than one full stop, such as `.co.uk`, you can't rely on regular expressions alone, you need to have a list of them. Note they are not Top Level Domains, but second level domains instead. This is how you fetch the list and process it: `wget https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat -o /dev/null -O - | awk '!/\/\/|^$/{gsub("*.","");print length,$0}' | sort -rnsk1,1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | xargs -i sed -i 's/\.{}$//' domains.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

### Single String Replacement

Here's how I did it with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) using the <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`H`**</kbd> option and then by replacing **`.com`** with **`<nothing leaving it blank>`** and the other options set as listed below in the screen shot. This will work with the **Search Mode** set to **Regular Expression** or as **Normal Search** too by the way.

> **Instructions**
>
> 1. Press <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`H`**</kbd> in Notepad++
> 2. Put `.com` in the **Find what** field
> 3. Leave the **Replace with** field empty with nothing nor any white space
> 4. Be sure the **Wrap around** option is checked
> 5. Select either the **Regular expression** or the **Normal** option within the **Search Mode** section
> 6. Press the <kbd>**`Replace All`**</kbd> option

[image]

### Before

```
i.gr-assets.com
instacam.com
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.com
```

### After

```
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
```

---

### Multiple String Replacement

Here's how I did it with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) using the <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`H`**</kbd> option and then by replacing **`(.com|.net|.biz|.uk)`** top level domains separated by pipes within the parenthesis just like that and replace those with **`<nothing leaving it blank>`** and the other options set as listed below in the screen shot. This will only work with the **Regular Expression** option.

> **Instructions**
>
> 1. Press <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`H`**</kbd> in Notepad++
> 2. Put `(.com|.net|.biz|.uk)` in the **Find what** field
>
>    - Your top level domains will each be separated by a pipe symbol (`|`) within the parenthesis—this tells it to match all strings within the parenthesis separated by a pipe
> 3. Leave the **Replace with** field empty with nothing nor any white space
> 4. Be sure the **Wrap around** option is checked
> 5. Select the **Regular expression** option within the **Search Mode** section
> 6. Press the <kbd>**`Replace All`**</kbd> option

[image]

### Before

```
i.gr-assets.com
instacam.com
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.com
i.gr-assets.net
instacam.net
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.net
i.gr-assets.biz
instacam.biz
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.biz
i.gr-assets.uk
instacam.uk
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo.uk
```

### After

```
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
i.gr-assets
instacam
r4---sn-bg0e7n7r.googlevideo
```

Comment: not only for .com. Like this, I have so many top level domain names. In a text file, in each domain name, i want to remove the top level domain name. But here some domain names has more than one full stop –

Comment: What with "domain names has more than one full stop"? You'd need a list of existing TLDs.

Comment: @simlev That's how I provided it for the OP and I assume you want the Op to read that comment though but each TLD will need to be specified in the regex for sure so that's how I provided the answer as I know how to complete that task with the Notepad++ app. Vinayakumar - I'm assuming this is what you need and not something to populate all TLDs automatically so you will need to specify those as I wrote in the answer above. I apologize if there's something I'm missing (from either one of you). Respectfully~

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your list has one URL per line. You could use this regular expression to remove the TLD's:

```
[.][^.]*$
```

Like this:

[image]